# Mechanize send a POST to populate data on a page

Tags: ruby, post, mechanize

I have a site that sends a POST to populate some data on a page. I usually look at the POST in Charles Proxy and pass the parameters like so:

```
bot.post('https://www.google.com?', {
        "parameter" => "value",
        "SESSION_parameter_ID" => "value2})
```

However, when I look at the request in Charles it is just sending text like this:

```
callCount=1
page=/eplus/mao.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=pBillPayHistory&_nfls=false
httpSessionId=2GQQQj3McPh2vQzvxnFb5KM9qgfn80Sqv2L8sC16p66nvxc5yJv5!1006025334
scriptSessionId=22A83635CAD97A33C8255AC8D559FD27672
c0-scriptName=BillingService
```

How do I send a POST to a URL and send the request parameters as text?

Comment: Do you mean the 'form' tab isn't showing in Charles? Check the content-type header of the request.

Comment: yes, the form tab isn't showing.  Just Headers, Text, Hex, Javascript and Raw.

Comment: The content type of the request header is text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Content-Type header should be: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So try:

```
bot.post url, vars, ({'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```